# What is preventing querySelectorAll from working on all elements with the same class in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to produce a swipe delete effect for li elements in a list similar to what you see in ios when you delete text messages. I have here a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPQBWj) that demonstrates exactly what I'm looking for. As you can see in this example, the first li element can be dragged to the left revealing a delete button. The problem is, I've been trying to get this effect to be applied to all li elements on a list and not just the first one. As you will see in this example, the second li element regardless of sharing the same classes as the first li element, isn't able to be dragged to the left. It just doesn't work. I've been told a solution would be to put querySelectorAll instead of querySelector in my js to have the same effect work for all li elements that share the same classes however that hasn't worked either. The codepen demo I have a link to above uses querySelector so you will see that the first li element has the effect I want applied to all li elements. So you can drag it to the left and see it working but notice if you change querySelector to querySelectorAll, nothing works. Any ideas? thanks.

```
<ul class="messages">
<li>
    <div class="message">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <time datetime="2014-08-22">Friday</time>
    </div>
    <button class="button-delete">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="message">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <time datetime="2014-08-22">Friday</time>
    </div>
    <button class="button-delete">Delete</button>
</li>
 </ul>


<style>
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
}



.messages {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
padding:0;
}

.messages li {
position:relative;
list-style-type:none;
min-height:75px;
}

.messages li:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:28px;
height:1px;
background-color:#e6e6e8;
}

.message {
position:relative;
z-index:2;
display:block;
padding:8px 28px 28px 28px;
background-color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;
}

.message:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:12px;
right:14px;
width:9px;
height:13px;

}

.message * {
-moz-user-select:none;
}

.message h3 {
margin:0 0 3px 0;
color:#000;
font-size:16px;
letter-spacing:.15px;
}

.message p {
margin:0;
font-size:14px;
color:#8e8e93;
letter-spacing:.8px;

}

.message time {
position:absolute;
top:10px;
right:31px;
font-size:14px;
color:#8e8e93;
letter-spacing:.8px;
}

.button-delete {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
width:82px;
margin:0;
border:none;
background-color:#ff3b30;
color:#fff;
font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
letter-spacing:.4px;
} 
</style>


<script>
var transformStyle = prefix() + 'Transform',
transitionStyle = prefix() + 'Transition',
message = document.querySelector('.message'),
buttonDelete = document.querySelector('.button-delete'),
hammer = new Hammer(message, {dragLockToAxis: true, dragBlockHorizontal: true}),
min = -(buttonDelete.offsetWidth), max = 0,
moveX = 0, startX = 0, added = 0, speed, friction = 0;

hammer.on('panstart', function() {
message.style[transitionStyle] = 'none';
});

hammer.on('panleft panright', function(e) {

moveX = startX + e.deltaX;

if (moveX < min) {
    friction = startX > min ? min/1.5 : startX;
    moveX = friction + (e.deltaX/3);
}

if (moveX <= max) {
    message.style[transformStyle] = 'translateX(' + moveX + 'px)';
}

});

hammer.on('panend', function(e) {

speed = .2 / (Math.abs(e.velocityX) + 1);

added += e.deltaX;

if (added < min/2) {
    startX = min;
}
else if (added > Math.abs(min/2)) {
    startX = max;
}

message.style[transitionStyle] = 'all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out';
message.style[transformStyle] = 'translateX(' + startX + 'px)';

added = 0;

});

function prefix() {

var styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, ''),
    pre = (Array.prototype.slice
        .call(styles)
        .join('')
        .match(/-(moz|webkit|ms)-/) || (styles.OLink === '' && ['', 'o'])
    )[1];

return pre[0].toUpperCase() + pre.substr(1);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems hammer.js works only on one element.

https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/master/hammer.js#L369

You Have to use querySelectorAll() then a loop over the elements applying a new Hammer on each.

```
messages = document.querySelectorAll('.message');

[].forEach.call(messages, function(message) {
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNQOrO

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. I've been scratching my head over this for some time.

Answer (score 1):

The `.querySelectorAll()` method returns a **list** of nodes. You have to iterate through the list and operate on each node individually with your own code. (You tagged your question with the jQuery tag, so I'll point out that you can let jQuery do that for you.)